# Android RatingBar (filling next star)

Tags: android, ratingbar

I have the following RatingBar:

```
<RatingBar
                android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:numStars="5"
                android:max="5"
                android:stepSize="1.0"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"/>
```

When I press the left part of a star - it is selected, but when I press the right part - the following star is selected. I need the star I click on to be selected whichever part of it I click. 
Help me please to understand what is wrong.

Comment: did you using `setOnTouchListener` ??

Comment: http://sampleprogramz.com/android/ratingbar.php

Comment: try to remove the android:layout_marginTop or the parent container padding

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya No, I didn't

Answer (score 27):

It is perhaps an unfortunate side effect of `RatingBar` extending `ProgressBar`, which internally uses a `int` progress with rounding (rather than `ceil`) to go from a `float` seek position to a `int` progress. The best solution I have found is to set your `stepSize` to `0.01` rather then `1`, then set

```
rb.setOnRatingBarChangeListener( new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onRatingChanged( final RatingBar ratingBar, final float rating, final boolean fromUser ) {
        if ( fromUser ) {
            ratingBar.setRating( Math.ceil(rating) );
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for your time!

Comment: This should be the selected answer

Comment: getting error - setRating(float) in RatingBar cannot be applied to (double)

Comment: Great answer, thanks a lot!
It also worked for me with step size 0.5 and it has less animations when the star is filled with the setRating inside the listener. Because when the user taps on the right half of the start, the ratingBar component anyway fills the hole star.

Answer (score 2):

I spent a lot of time trying to solve this problem in Xamarin.Droid. The library used in the project seems to be a little different. In case someone is going through this problem and hasn't been able to solve it yet, this solved the problem here:

First, I set the **stepSize to 0.01**. Then I needed to import the **Android.Widget.RatingBar** into **Holder** class, inherited the interface **IOnRatingBarChangeListener** and implemented the method **OnRatingChanged** as **virtual**. Within the method I did the **rounding** and then I **called the method inside the Event**.

```
using static Android.Widget.RatingBar;

namespace Holder
{
    public class Holder : RecyclerView.ViewHolder, IOnRatingBarChangeListener
    {
        public Question question;
        public TextView tvQuestion;
        public RatingBar rbRating;
        public Holder(Android.Views.View itemView, OnRatingChangeListener listener) : base(itemView)
        {
            tvQuestion = (TextView)itemView.FindViewById(Resource.Id.tvQuestion);
            rbRating = (RatingBar)itemView.FindViewById(Resource.Id.rbRating);
            rbRating.RatingBarChange += (o, e) =>
            {
                OnRatingChanged(rbRating, rbRating.Rating, true);
                listener.onRatingChange(question, rbRating.Rating);
            };
        }

        public virtual void OnRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, bool fromUser)
        {
            if (fromUser)
            {
                var newRating = (Math.Ceiling(rating));
                ratingBar.Rating = (float)newRating;
            }
        }
    }
}
```