# Rating Bar not working properly on small screen

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, ratingbar

Default rating bar of android with custom theme not working properly because when we tap on specific star then next star automatically selected and for unselect star we need to tap on star previous 2 from current star that i want to unselect

**My XML Code**

```
<RatingBar
                        android:id="@+id/rate_bar"
                        style="@style/StarRatingBarCheckout"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_5"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_5"
                        android:numStars="5" />
```

Style for rating bar is **StarRatingBarCheckout** that i have mentioned in **style.xml**

```
  <style name="StarRatingBarCheckout" parent="@android:style/Widget.RatingBar">
        <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/star_rating_bar_full_checkout</item>
        <item name="android:minHeight">35dip</item>
        <item name="android:maxHeight">35dip</item>
        <item name="android:stepSize">1</item>
    </style>
```

star_rating_bar_full_checkout.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/background"
        android:drawable="@drawable/star_ratingbar_full_empty_checkout"
        />
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress"
        android:drawable="@drawable/star_ratingbar_full_empty_checkout"
        />
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/progress"
        android:drawable="@drawable/star_ratingbar_full_filled_checkout" />
</layer-list>
```

Same code working well on large screen

Comment: I didn't face with this problem but allegedly It seems this issue is known
Did you check this link?:
[https://stackoverflow.com/q/33798521/9391162](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33798521/9391162)

Comment: yes i have checked https://stackoverflow.com/q/33798521/9391162 link but its not working

Answer (score 0):

Try to put **android:stepSize="1"** into ratingBar tag

Comment: i have added android:stepSize="1" in ratingbar tag but still not working